# Why RiverPod FutureProvider does not make the Drawer to be rebuilt automatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-riverpod

My application has a Drawer that contains options per company branch, which are loaded from a repository using a `FutureProvider provider`. Using `provider.when(loading:...)`, a message is shown while data is retrieved, but it is never replaced by the ListView with proper branches options, as I thought it would happen. I have to close the drawer, and open it again, for the `data:...` part of the `when` to be run.

This is the definition of the provider:

```
final branchRepositoryProvider = FutureProvider<BranchRepository>((ref) async {
  var repository = await BranchRepository.create();
  developer.log('BranchRepositoryProvider created.');
  return repository;
```

And this is the code that makes use of it:

```
class NavigationDrawer extends ConsumerWidget {
  const NavigationDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    AsyncValue<BranchRepository> provider =
        ref.read(repositories.branchRepositoryProvider);
    developer.log('Got branch provider.');
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(...),
            ] +
            provider.when(
                data: (repository) => branchOptions(context, repository),
                loading: () =>
                    [const ListTile(title: Text('Reading the database...'))],
                error: (e, s) => [
                  ListTile(title: Text('Something when wrong:\n$e'))]),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<ListTile> branchOptions(
      BuildContext context, BranchRepository repository) {
    developer.log('Creating branch options...');
    var branches = getBranches(repository);
    ...
  }

  Map<int, String> getBranches(BranchRepository repository) {
    developer.log('Iterating over ids...');
    ...
  }
}
```

Messages in functions `branchOptions(...)` and `getBranches(...)` are shown only after the second click.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `ref.read` in a builder.  In general, you should use `ref.watch` in a builder, and `ref.read` only for callbacks.  Otherwise, the builder isn't set to rebuild when the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

As Randal Schwartz suggested, my mistake was using `ref.read` instead of `ref.watch`, as

```
AsyncValue<BranchRepository> provider =
    ref.watch(repositories.branchRepositoryProvider);
```

With that change, it is working now.